# Custom straight line path in xml

Tags: android, android-drawable

I would like to have a drawable that looks like the following drawing.

[image: Desired outcome]

I imagine I need 4 lines; 2 for the tip and one on each side. I don't understand how to:

- Give the 2 tip lines a length (ex.: 5dp)
- Position lines relative to each other (stacked horizontally)
- Allow the side lines to expand to fill the parent (with one having X% of space and the other (100-tip-X)%.

This is what I have so far:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#336699"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="135"
            android:toDegrees="135">
            <shape android:shape="line">
                <stroke
                    android:width="1dp"
                    android:color="#330000"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:toDegrees="45">
            <shape android:shape="line">
                <stroke
                    android:width="1dp"
                    android:color="#000033"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#336699"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I would recommend using 9Patch for this

Comment: Good point. I ended up doing that and it works fine. Thanks.